# Where is my.cnf or mysql.conf on Mac OS Catalina?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064, macos-catalina

I would like to change something in the mysql configuration file but I cannot find it in `/etc/my.cnf` or in `/usr/local/mysql`.

Do you know where I can find this file?

Note that I installed mysql from the official website by a .pkg file not Homebrew.

Thank you.

Comment: looked in `/etc` ?  i made same mistake (not using homebrew) ... that is where the .pkg placed the my.cnf (on Mojave).

Comment: Do you suggest that I use Homebrew?

Comment: yes , i did this before i knew better.  But now my box has both (brewed and .pkg'ed in) and i still have not found a safe method for scrapping the .pkg'ed in version, so am stuck with a lagging version atm).  Homebrew has **many** advantages, and some not-so-obvious cons, but one of its major advantage is that you can always remove a brewed package (.02).

Comment: Alright, I will give it a try, thank you.

Comment: before : Run mysql --help and you will see Default options are read from the following files in the given order: /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf. ALSO, i avoided Catalina like the Covid plague, so am not sure. You may have to be root to 'ls' and see files in some of these directories.

Comment: I agree with you, Catalina is a plague.

Answer (score 5):

In the **macOS Catalina**

```
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 1):

As @YvesLeBorg suggested, the my.cnf file can be find at  /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf or /usr/local/etc/my.cnf  or ~/.my.cnf

In order to identify where the my.cnf is, permet a `cat` on each of those links.

Also, remember the different my.cnf file locations can be found by running `mysql --help`